# "Unable to serialize the session state" error on deploying the ASP.Net site

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code runs fine in my local system but throws the following error when accessing the site after deploying. The session state for this is not declared anywhere in the application. Kindly help me on how to handle this.

Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
```

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.DataView' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +7736011
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +258
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +111
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +161
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +51
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +410
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +134
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1577

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.]
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1662
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer) +606
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream) +239
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length) +72
   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +116
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +560
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Answer (score 3):

If you deploy to a single server, just make sure the SessionMode is set to InProc. The setting may have gone missing during deployment.

When you want to use multiple servers you'll have to make sure everything you put into the Session is serializable.

From the error, you are now storing a `System.Data.DataView` in your session. I'm not sure if that is wise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using out of process session data storage, this would require that any type you add to Session be Serializable. This means that you cannot add any class to Session and expect it to work smoothly. Many of the third party classes and BCL classes are non serializable and hence cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are either using StateServer or Sql Server mode to store Session objects and DataView is not serializable. Instead of just using InProc state server, as Henk advises, I'd rather just put serializable objects in `Session` if you don't want surprises when the asp.net worker process is recycled and all your Session objects are lost.